# add modal-header element to opened alert box in bootbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

To show **alert** messages I use [bootboxjs.com](http://bootboxjs.com/) bootstrap jquery plugin.
after call `bootbox.alert("Hello world!");` method , it generate below code and show a modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- dialog body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        Hello world!
      </div>
      <!-- dialog buttons -->
      <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see generated modal has not `modal-header` element to show a header message by default.
i want all of alert boxes have a default header contains a custom message like : `System Says :`.

i know that there is a dialog() method in `bootboxjs` for show custom message that Could have `modal-header` element. But use dialog() need to write and repeat some lines to show a simple alert box.

Have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [options object](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-dialog-options) to specify the title, and it will generate the header you're after:

```js
bootbox.alert({
    title: "I'm the title!",
    message: "I'm the message!",
    callback: function(){ console.log("I handled the callback!"); }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but if anyone who's looking for `custom header for bootbox`, you can just pass your HTML directly to the `title` option of the modal.

```
bootbox.dialog({
  message: 'Your Message',
  title: '<div><h4>Your custom HTML Title</h4></div>'
});
```